My custom magento section doesn't appear local storage
In my understanding, magento store private customer data in a local storage under the mage-cache-storage key. Therefore, I'm trying to create a custom section in the local storage to store my own defined data. I have followed some instruction i found online, however, when i inspect my website to see the mage-cache-storage, i didn't see my custom section at all.
This is how i did:
I had an existing module so i added an di.xml in the /etc/frontend folder
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="mage-cache-storage" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="custom_section" xsi:type="string">Uet\Calendar\CustomerData\CustomSection</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>

Then i created a file to retrieve the section data in the path app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/CustomerData/CustomerSection.php
<?php
namespace Uet\Calendar\CustomerData;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
{   

    public function getSectionData()
    {
        return [
            'occasions' => 'test',
            'categories' => 'test',
        ];
    }
}

And use the magento js library to retrive the data
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 'domReady!'], function (customerData) {
        var customSection = customerData.get('custom_section');
        console.log(customSection);
    });

I have clean the cache and all but I still no where to see my custom_section in local storage
Edit: So i have solved this by adding the sections.xml and changed the tag name like the following comment
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="/calendar/index/index/">
        <section name="custom_section"/>
    </action>
</config>


sections.xml in the /etc/frontend/sections.xml do create this file as well, here is the core file vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml
and istead of this <argument name="mage-cache-storage" xsi:type="array">
use
<argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">

wow thanks this solved my problem ! =)

@GiaKhánh That's great, Please accept answer as well
